# Dart/Flutter not changing page with Inkwell and Gesture detector

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, containers, gesturedetector

I am trying to use  Inkwell or Gesture detector to navigate to page 2, but it is saying "Undefined name 'context'". Hope someone can help! :))
It is a google maps stack container and other group of containers on the top. When click on the containers on top, it redirects to the 2page.

Main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'woocommerce/woocommerce_api.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Page1());
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {

  //********************************** GOOGLE MAPS *****************************************

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MapView(),
    );
  }
}

class MapView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapViewState createState() => _MapViewState();
}

class _MapViewState extends State<MapView> {

  CameraPosition _initialLocation = CameraPosition(target: LatLng(0.0, 0.0));
  GoogleMapController mapController;

  final Geolocator _geolocator = Geolocator();
  Position _currentPosition;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getCurrentLocation();
  }
  _getCurrentLocation() async {
    await _geolocator
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high)
        .then((Position position) async {
      setState(() {
        // Store the position in the variable
        _currentPosition = position;

        print('CURRENT POS: $_currentPosition');

        // For moving the camera to current location
        mapController.animateCamera(
          CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
            CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude),
              zoom: 13.0,
            ),
          ),
        );
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // Determining the screen width & height
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;


    //********************************** GOOGLE MAPS SCREEN **********************************
    return Container(
      height: height,
      width: width,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[

            GoogleMap(
              initialCameraPosition: _initialLocation,
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
              zoomControlsEnabled: false,
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                mapController = controller;
              },
            ),

            ClipOval(
              child: Material(
                color: Color(0xffeb5c68), // button color
                child: InkWell(
                  splashColor: Color(0xffda1b2b), // inkwell color
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 56,
                    height: 56,
                    child: Icon(Icons.my_location),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    mapController.animateCamera(
                      CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                        CameraPosition(
                          target: LatLng(
                            _currentPosition.latitude,
                            _currentPosition.longitude,
                          ),
                          zoom: 13.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),


            //********************************** ORDERS **********************************

            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 550, bottom: 50),
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                children: getTechniciansInArea(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Technician> getTechies() {
    List<Technician> techies = [];
    //For esting...
    // for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

      //Technician myTechy = Technician(name:'Apotheken', phoneNum: 'Address store');
      Technician myTechy = Technician("Store name test", "Address store ", "Address costumer", 529.3, 4, "Available", "fdfd");

      techies.add(myTechy);
    //}
    return techies;
  }

  List<Widget> getTechniciansInArea() {
    List<Technician> techies2 = getTechies();
    List<Widget> cards = [];
    for (Technician techy in techies2) {
      cards.add(technicianCard(techy));
    }
    return cards;
  }
}

Widget technicianCard(Technician technician) {
  return
    InkWell( // when click...
     child:
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
          width: 180,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
            color: Colors.white,
            boxShadow: [
               BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey,
                blurRadius: 0.5,
              ),],
          ),
          child:
          Column(
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[

              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(height: 5,),
                     Text(technician.name, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold), textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                       SizedBox(height: 10,),
                        Text("AS: " + technician.phoneNum, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
                         SizedBox(height: 10,),
                          Text("AC: " + technician.address, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
                           SizedBox(height: 30,),
                ],
              ),

              GestureDetector(
                child:
                          Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          width: 120.0,
                          height: 40.0,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                            color: Color(0xffeb5c68),
                          ),
                              child:
                              Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[


                                Text("REQUEST", textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                              ]
                                )
                          ),
                  onLongPress: (){

              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2()),
                );
              },
              )
                  ]
              )
              ),
       onTap: () {

         Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2()),
                );
       }
        );
    }

    //********************************** PAGE 2 **********************************
class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Your orders"),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Woocommerce_api.dart:

```
class Technician {
  String name;
  String phoneNum;
  String address;
  double rate;
  String status;
  int rating;
  String occupation;

  Technician(this.name, this.phoneNum, this.address, this.rate, this.rating, this.status, this.occupation);
  //Technician({this.name, this.phoneNum, this.address, this.rate, this.rating, this.status, this.occupation});

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send BuildContexti to function. does not see the correct context. likewise, you need to add it to the top. Set the context no matter where you called.

```
Widget technicianCard(Technician technician, BuildContext context)//add here
 {
      .....
      ...
      ..
    }
```

Comment: yeap. i forget :)